# Find non-successive duplicates in large text file

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a few gigabytes of web app logs that I need to extract customer data from for a client (who didnt keep proper backups.)

So far I've cleaned up the logs a fair bit, and I can see the light at the end of the tunnel. However, I'm realizing there are a lot of duplicate entries, it seems everytime a customer used this web app the same data was stored in the logs, heres a simplified example:

```
initial_date=Jul-26-2015&report_center=0&last_name=bar&first_name=foo&sex=M&birthday=Sep-26-1985&sin=123456789&drivers_license=&address1=414+stackoverflow+Street&residence_type=1&address2=Apartment+103&datemovein=Feb-02-2013&postal=a1a1a1&city=townsville&prov=ontario&country=Canada&telephone=5555555555&cell_phone=5555556666

initial_date=Jan-24-2014&report_center=0&last_name=blah&first_name=steve&sex=M&birthday=aug-11-1983&sin=987654321&drivers_license=&address1=12+stackoverflow+Street&residence_type=1&address2=&datemovein=Jun-02-2011&postal=a9a9a9&city=cityville&prov=ontario&country=Canada&telephone=5551111111&cell_phone=5552222222

initial_date=Jul-26-2015&report_center=0&last_name=bar&first_name=foo&sex=M&birthday=Sep-26-1985&sin=123456789&drivers_license=&address1=414+stackoverflow+Street&residence_type=1&address2=Apartment+103&datemovein=Feb-02-2013&postal=a1a1a1&city=townsville&prov=ontario&country=Canada&telephone=5555555555&cell_phone=5555556666
```

I want to match the unique entries, ultimately to remove the rest.
I've attempted to use regex & positive lookahead to do the job, but from what Ive read it seems that will only work if the duplicates are successive, which some are, but many are not. Is there a way for me to use regex alone to accomplish this?

Comment: You can do that with a lookahead, but it will probably be too slow.  What tool/language are you using?

Comment: Using a line sort would loose positional relationships. If you don't care, simple string compare would be the fastes. But, for a 1-off type of thing, if you used a line oriented regex of the type Find `(?m)^(.*)\n([\S\s]*?^\1)` Replace `$2` in a while ( oldlength != newlength){ oldlength = newlength; str = str.replace( regex, "$2"); newlength = str.length ) } loop it would be slow, but effective to cut a big layer of _slag_.

Comment: I would drop this into a database first. It will make it easier to clean up and extract other data later on.

Answer (score 0):

There's no sane reason to use a regular expression for this; `sort -u` will do what you specified by example.

Comment: Why are you assuming it's linux/unix? It could be Windows, or some tool, a text editor...

Comment: Why are you assuming Windows doesn't have `sort`? …

Comment: Well, it does, but not with the `-u` option.